# drag not working in relative layout in android studio

Tags: android

i have my relative layout in my mainactivity xml but drag is not working the element automatically moves to the corner

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="294dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/aspertime" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Provide your complete code on how you are using drag and drop

Comment: Check my answer for sample idea.Provide your complete code or sample code to get exact requirement.

Answer (score 0):

setOnTouchListener to ImageView and do your required calculation and perform translation like following.

```
imageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                switch (motionEvent.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        view.setTranslationX(motionEvent.getX());// perform your own calculation
                        view.setTranslationY(motionEvent.getY());// perform your own calculation
                        break;
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                            view.setTranslationX(motionEvent.getX());
                            view.setTranslationY(motionEvent.getY());
                            break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }

        });
```

However this is very basic sample code.
Happy Coding.
Thanks